# Method Paginate Does not exist in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, pagination

```
public function index(Tag $tag){

    //$posts=$tag->posts;

    $posts=$tag->posts->paginate(10);

    return view('posts.index' , compact('posts'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relationship, not property:

```
$tag->posts()->paginate(10);
```

When you're using property, the query is already executed and you can't use the `paginate()` method on a collection.

Comment: not working bro . its a error of pagination . when i return value of $posts , its shows exact values but using post() giving some error

Comment: @HaroonZaqoota I'm pretty sure the code above is correct. What error do you get?

Comment: how can i upload user image . in laravel . bcz <img src="{{ asset('img/basic/logo.png') }}" > this code is working . but how can i get user->image..............<img src="{{ asset('uploads/images/{{$user->image}}') }}" > this second code give me error

Comment: @HaroonZaqoota you should start from reading [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads) If you'll have a problem, you should start a new question and post all related code you've wrote, so someone could be able to help you with the issue.